# swagger try it out redirect to login

Tags: laravel, swagger, middleware, swagger-ui, content-type

I mount my swagger api documentation (with login to protect my route of "api/documentation"). The documentation UI it's ok but when i want execute "try it out"... Ups! Something going wrong...

I found that the class "Authenticate" (extends Middleware) redirect to login if not find the header `this.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';`. Then, i gone to the view (resources/view/vendor/l5-swagger/index.blade.php) and set the correct headers:

```php
    requestInterceptor: function() {
      this.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token; 
      this.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      this.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
      return this;
    }
```

The problem it's that when i "retry it out" the result it's a redirect to login again. And i pass the headers on the curl:

```sh
 curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/mediador/xxx" -H "accept: */*" -H "Authorization: Bearer tokenGenerated" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
```

Here an example that how i documentate my calls at the comments:

```
/**
 * Insertamos un nuevo mediador
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse Respuesta formateada para la api del create
 *
 * @OA\Post(
 *     path="/api/mediador/",
 *     tags={"Mediador"},
 *     description="Insert data from mediador profile",
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *       required=true,
 *       @OA\MediaType(
 *           mediaType="application/json",
 *           @OA\Schema(
 *               type="object",
 *               required={"id_user_crm","email","nombre_usuario"},
 *               @OA\Property(
 *                   property="id_user_crm",
 *                   description="ID from sugar ",
 *                   type="string"
 *               ),
 *               @OA\Property(
 *                   property="email",
 *                   description="Email from profile",
 *                   type="string"
 *               ),
 *               @OA\Property(
 *                   property="nombre_usuario",
 *                   description="Name of user",
 *                   type="string"
 *               )
 *           )
 *       )
 *   ),
 *   @OA\Response(response="200", description="This is ok"),
 *   @OA\Response(response="401", description="Not logged with OAUTH token"),
 *   @OA\Response(response="403", description="Wrong data or duplicated fields in DataBase"),
 * )
```

**Why redirect to login yet? How can i set the data**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution from my problem:

Swagger try read as html if you doesn't give the `Response` with correct `"mediaType"`. Here put a complete comment to work with Swagger ui:

```
 /** 
 * @OA\Post(
 *     path="/api/mediador/",
 *     tags={"Mediador"},
 *     description="Insert data from mediador profile",
 *     @OA\RequestBody(
 *       required=true,
 *       @OA\MediaType(
 *           mediaType="application/json",
 *           @OA\Schema(
 *               type="object",
 *               required={"id_user_crm","email","nombre_usuario"},
 *               @OA\Property(
 *                   property="id_user_crm",
 *                   description="ID outside of this platform",
 *                   type="string"
 *               ),
 *               @OA\Property(
 *                   property="email",
 *                   description="Email from profile",
 *                   type="string"
 *               ),
 *               @OA\Property(
 *                   property="nombre_usuario",
 *                   description="Name of user",
 *                   type="string"
 *               )
 *           )
 *       )
 *   ),
 *   @OA\Response(
 *     response="200", description="Inserted data from mediador profiles",
 *     content={
 *          @OA\MediaType(
 *              mediaType="application/json",
 *              @OA\Schema(
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                           property="id",
 *                           type="integer",
 *                           description="The id generated"
 *                   ),
 *                  @OA\Property(
 *                         property="id_user_crm",
 *                         type="integer",
 *                         description="The reference id with the other platform"
 *                   )
 *              )
 *          )
 *     }
 *   ),
 *   @OA\Response(response="401", description="Not logged with OAUTH token"),
 *   @OA\Response(response="403", description="Wrong data or duplicated fields in DataBase"),
 * )
 */
```

With this comment before the function, read the `@OA\Response` and search `@OA\MediaType` to know what type of response returns the API REST.